# How to convert .img to usable VirtualBox format

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso-image, virtual-disk

I have a .img file for Windows 10, and I need to turn it into something which I can use in VirtualBox, such as an ISO, or turning it into a bootable virtual disk for an ICT project.

Comment: If this was Linux, I'd suggest `qemu-img convert`. On Windows, it's more fun to install Win1 yourself from floppy images

Answer (score 143, accepted):

1. Select a virtual machine by clicking its name in the VirtualBox window
2. Click the **Machine** menu at the top of the VirtualBox window, and click **Settings**
3. Click the **Storage** category in the Settings window
4. Right-click in the storage tree pane, and click **Add Floppy Controller**
5. Right-click the **Floppy Controller** device, and click [**Add Floppy Device**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBAIs.png)
6. Click the **Choose Disk** button in the prompt window that appears
7. Navigate to the floppy disk image file (.IMG) on your computer and double-click it

If that doesn't work, try renaming the .IMG as .ISO and mount it.

If that too doesn't work, use [**VBoxManage's *convertfromraw*** command](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-convertfromraw) as follows:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw --format VDI [filename].img [filename].vdi
```

Mount the VDI as a hard disk.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked, and a few days before the project was due.

Comment: Is this reversible?

Comment: @ThorSummoner: Try `VBoxManage clonehd --format RAW [filename].vdi [filename].img` (syntax help for *clonehd* [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi)).

Comment: Thanks! Renaming .img to .iso worked in my case, I had SharePoint 2013 Server.

Comment: The fully quallified command path is: /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage clonehd --format RAW [filename].vdi [filename].img

Comment: convertfromraw was the only way that worked for me to convert a Volumio.img into a VirtualBox vdi and boot from it.

Comment: Just a note it will not work if the image file converted is built for a different architecture. For example, you cannot convert a Raspian (ARM) image for use in VirtualBox (x86) using this method.

Comment: convertfromraw is what worked for me.

Comment: Will it work with an android rom ?

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 can mount .img files as a drive. This drive can then be accessed by a virtual machine.

1. In Windows Explorer, right click on the .img file, select Mount.
2. Start the virtual machine
3. In the Devices menu => Optical Drives => select the Host Drive created in step 1.

Comment: sometimes it wont , for e.g. i tried to mount an octopi img file in windows 10 and it said the image file is corrupt

Comment: I'm also experiencing a "corrupted image file" which came from a raspberry pi.

Comment: The Rasberry Pi images might be ARM processor based, instead of x86-based.